# Why is AWS Route 53 Host Redirecting to Elastic Beanstalk Server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, dns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

Using [Amazon's Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-beanstalk-environment.html), I created an Elastic Beanstalk application for a Wordpress/Woocommerce app. The EB domain contains a region, i.e., my-app.us-east-N.elasticbeanstalk.com. I followed the guide for using my own host (mysite.com), which I have set up on Route 53.

Whenever I hit mysite.com, I get a 301 redirect to my-app.us-east-N.elasticbeanstalk.com. I simply am using the A Alias record for mysite.com to point to that EB domain, exactly as in their guide. How do I stop it from redirecting? I dont want to use the EB domain, I want to use mysite.com to load the content coming from the EB domain. I havent yet found any AWS docs that explain this, the directions for doing what I want are incredibly simple (but dont seem to work).

Comment: Are you sure that it is not your app that is sending the redirect?

Comment: That is being explored currently, but an outsourced team is responsible for the app and currently I have no insight into it.

Comment: @DusanBajic yep you were right, the problem was with the WP application having been set up to redirect to the EB domain, there was no problem with Amazon.

That insight is useful, so if you wwant to post an answer below Ill accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in default AWS Elastic Beanstalk setup that would cause such redirect. You should check if it is your app that is sending the redirect (especially since the Wordpress is known to force the redirect to its default/configured site URL).

Comment: Yes, it was indeed Wordpress forcing a redirect to a default URL!